# implode of array results in RabbitMQ receiving empty msg body yet other publishers show the body

Tags: php, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, php-amqplib

The first one is receiving data from `$_POST` in a **login.php** which calls a function from another file through `require_once`, and the `$_POST` is populated as I can `echo` it to my login page and see it, but it doesn't make it to the queue on the message broker.

Here is the code that RabbitMQ receives but the message is empty:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
    use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
    include 'host_info.php';
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($address, 5672, $admin, $adminpass);
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    $channel->queue_declare('login', false, false, false, false);

    $data;
    function setMessage($arr) {
        $data = implode(',', $arr);

        echo $data;
        if (empty($data)) {
            echo 'Please input your email and/or password.';
            return;
        }
        return;
    }

    $msg = new AMQPMessage($data, array('delivery_mode'=> AMQPMEssage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT));
    $channel->basic_publish($msg,'', 'login');



    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
?>
```

And here is the code from another file that `RabbitMQ` receives and does have a body:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
    use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
    include 'host_info.php';
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($address, 5672, $admin, $adminpass);
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    $channel->queue_declare('login', false, false, false, false);

    $data = implode(' ', array_slice($argv, 1));
    if (empty($data)) {
        $data = 'Hello World!';
    }
    $msg = new AMQPMessage($data, array('delivery_mode'=> AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT));
    $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'login');

    echo '[x] Sent' , $data, "\n";
    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
?>
```

If there are any errors in these it is because I had to handtype out the second because it was on a VM and the bidirectional clipboard does not work.

edit: here is the code from **login.php**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include 'host_info.php';

    $email;
    $pass;
    $arr;

    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        require ('send_login_request.php');
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        $arr = array($email, $pass);
        setMessage($arr);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify a global variable in function, you need to use the `global` keyword

```php
    $data;
    function setMessage($arr) {
        global $data;
        $data = implode(',', $arr);

        echo $data;
        if (empty($data)) {
            echo 'Please input your email and/or password.';
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php